# Get Values from a Slick 2.0 Query in a case class form

Tags: scala, slick-2.0

I am trying to get an underlying querys case classes from a Scala Slick query, and it seems more difficult to me than it should be. Here is my compiler error:

`[info] Compiling 18 Scala sources to /home/target/scala-2.11/classes...
[error] /home/src/main/scala/com/core/address/AddressDAO.scala:30: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : scala.slick.lifted.Query[com.core.address.AddressDAO,com.core.protocol.Address,Seq]
[error]  required: Option[com.core.protocol.Address]
[error]       q`

Here is the method I have written:

```
  def getAddress(otherAddress: String): Future[Option[Address]] = {
    future {
      val q = for (addr <- addresses if (addr.address == otherAddress)) yield addr
      q
    }
```

Here is the Slick Schema:

```
class AddressDAO(tag: Tag) extends Table[Address](tag, "ADDRESSES") with DbConfig {

  def address = column[String]("ADDRESS", O.PrimaryKey)
  def hash160 = column[String]("HASH160")
  def n_tx = column[Long]("N_TX")
  def total_received = column[Double]("TOTAL_RECEIVED")
  def total_sent = column[Double]("TOTAL_SENT")
  def final_balance = column[Double]("FINAL_BALANCE")
  def * = (hash160, address, n_tx, total_received, total_sent, final_balance) <> (Address.tupled, Address.unapply)

}
```

What I want to do is expressed in the return type of the method `getAddress` which is `Future[Option[Address]]`. I want the first element that the database is finding. The type that is actually being returned is of type `scala.slick.lifted.Query[com.core.address.AddressDAO,com.core.protocol.Address,Seq]`

There does not seem to be any `execute` method or anything to kick start the query. I suspect this can be done with `for-comprehensions` but I cannot figure how to actually do it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am certainly no Slick expert, but after a quick perusal of the [docs](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/2.0.0/queries.html), I am wondering if maybe wrapping something like this in your `Future` would work:

```
addresses.filter(_.address === "givenAddressString").firstOption
```

Comment: Not found underneath this doc? http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/2.0.0-M3/api/index.html#scala.slick.lifted.Query

Comment: For one thing, I think that's outdated since 2.0.0 is no longer a milestone and is actually a thing. But you should also look at [Invoker](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/2.0.0/api/#scala.slick.jdbc.Invoker). As the docs say, "Queries are executed using methods defined in the Invoker trait (or UnitInvoker for the parameterless versions). There is an implicit conversion from Query, so you can execute any Query directly."

Comment: Thank you, that was my disconnect :)

Comment: Glad to help. Good luck with your project!

Answer (score 1):

You have to actually run your query.

q.firstOption is what you probably want to use:

```
def getAddress(otherAddress: String): Future[Option[Address]] = {
    future {
      val q = for (addr <- addresses if (addr.address == otherAddress)) yield addr
      q.firstOption
    }
```

PS. Simply filtering addresses for the given value of address is indeed more concise. And of course the performance of this query depends on whether you have an index on that field and the size of your table :)